# How to force nginx to resolve DNS (of a dynamic hostname) everytime when doing proxy_pass?

Tags: linux, nginx

I am using nginx/0.7.68, running on CentOS, with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ***;
    index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm default.php;

    location / {
            root   /***;
            proxy_pass   http://***:8888;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    # where *** is my variables
```

The `proxy_pass` is to a DNS record whose IP changes frequently. Nginx caches the outdated IP address, resulting in a request to the wrong IP address.

How can I stop nginx from caching the IP address, when it is outdated?

Comment: looking through the nginx source, it does appear nginx is hardcoded to cache resolves for their TTL - what's the TTL on your dynamic dns?

Comment: TTL on my ddns is 60s, the default value of dyndns.com

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956979/error-with-ip-with-nginx-as-reverse-proxy

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/560632/some-nginx-reverse-proxy-configs-stops-working-once-a-day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an intriguing question and AFAIK that's not going to work well. You can try to use the [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module and use the directives for failover to see if it works as a hack.

2018 edit: a lot of things changed. Check the [answer by @ohaal](https://serverfault.com/a/593003/48752) to get real information about this.

Comment: surprisingly when i changed to upstream, everything worked as expected. I'll then mark this as correct answer

Comment: According to the documentation, there's a special upstream `server` flag `resolve` that's only available in the commercial version (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server)

Comment: @gansbrest that site seems to be some kind of spammy site? i'd ask that you remove your response.

Comment: It's a shame that in 2020 the upstream module still doesn't fix this issue.  Resolving the address once and using that forever is useless.

Answer (score 163):

Accepted answer didn't work for me on nginx/1.4.2.

[Using a variable in `proxy_pass` forces re-resolution of the DNS names](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832) because NGINX treats variables differently to static configuration. From the [NGINX `proxy_pass` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> Parameter value can contain variables. In this case, if an address is specified as a domain name, the name is searched among the described server groups, and, if not found, is determined using a resolver.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    set $backend "http://dynamic.example.com:80";
    proxy_pass $backend;
    ...
}
```

Note: A resolver (i.e. the name server to use) MUST be available and configured for this to work (and entries inside a `/etc/hosts` file won't be used in a lookup).

[By default, version 1.1.9 or later versions of NGINX cache answers using the TTL value of a response](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/bec516bec93cbe8bf9d6b9698901caa180d9cf72) and an optional [`valid` parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) allows the cache time to be overridden:

```
resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353 valid=30s;
```

[Before version 1.1.9, tuning of caching time was not possible, and nginx **always cached answers for the duration of 5 minutes.**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

Comment: wouldn't this force a dns query on every single request? that sounds like awful performance...

Comment: No, read the source. `In such setup ip address of "foo.example.com" will be looked up dynamically and result will be cached for 5 minutes.` I've added it to the answer for clarity.

Comment: After spending most of my day on this - on Ubuntu 12.04 with nginx 1.1.19, `set` inside `location` doesn't work properly. Beware

Comment: This solution worked with me, however I couldn't find a reference for the 5 minutes TTL.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver
`By default, nginx caches answers using the TTL value of a response. An optional valid parameter allows overriding it:
resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353 valid=30s;`

Comment: It could be wrong, it's based on the source link I provided in my answer. *In such setup ip address of "foo.example.com" will be looked up
dynamically and result will be cached for 5 minutes.*

Comment: I just implemented this. I'm doing set in server, not location.

Comment: Note: for docker, it's DNS resolver resides at 127.0.0.11, so for development, I use this: `resolver 127.0.0.11 [::1]:5353 valid=15s;`

Comment: Found more references to the 5 min default cache expiry in old versions in this patch http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2011-November/001466.html. Current source here. https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/27b3d3dcca5fcc82350a823881f3d06161327b59/src/core/ngx_resolver.c#L199

Comment: @omribahumi 4 years and this comment is still useful. I was getting 500 from nginx, and had no clue.

Comment: Here's a really nasty gotcha that lost me over a day trying to debug:
If you use a variable in the proxy_pass directive, the interpretation of the path changes. When you do this, the path of the original request is completely overridden and replaced by the path given in proxy_pass. You must use a proxy_pass without a path in the url in order to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: I had to change it to `set $backend "http://dynamic.example.com:80$request_uri";`, otherwise the request path will be empty (as the comment above me also mentions)

Comment: FYI support for set in stream blocks was added in 1.19. Was not possible before.

Comment: Does this work with upstreams? Ie, if I have an upstream `upstream1` and change my config from `proxy_pass https://upstream1` to `set $somevar upstream1; proxy_pass https://$somevar` can I get similar results?

Comment: "Note: A resolver (i.e. the name server to use) MUST be available ", for those not aware this means you need to set up a DNS server. dnsmasq is easy to setup (https://wiki.debian.org/dnsmasq).

Comment: Won't this kill performance to be performing a DNS lookup on every single request?

Comment: @MrMesees read the part about cache

Comment: This worked very well for me.  In my case with Kubernetes..I added in the server {} stanza `resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;` (That is the common IP for Weavworks dns resolver). Then I set a variable for just the host also in server{} `set $backend_host "nextcloud-service.nextcloud.svc.cluster.local";` .   Finally in the server{location{}} stanza I add `proxy_pass http://$backend_host:8129;`

Comment: I found that if the hostname being resolved is just a shortname (no domain part), as would likely be the case for Docker service discovery by service hostname, then your need to add a trailing dot, e.g. `set $backend_host "http://backend.:1234/abc";`. Otherwise the hostname is resolved once at startup, as though a variable was not being used.

Comment: @LonKaut regarding Kubernetes resolver, the 10.96.0.10 IP is a dynamic address (meaning I have a different address in my cluster). I've created custom entrypoint for nginx dockerfile that replaces conf values with envsubst and I fetch resolver IP with `nslookup kubernetes.default | grep -E '^Server:\s+' | sed -E 's/^Server:\s+//'` (must be run during container startup, inside the Pod). Note: dnsutils (ubuntu) must be installed in the container.

Comment: On Ubuntu servers, `resolver` is `127.0.0.53`.

Answer (score 15):

There is valuable information in gansbrest comment and ohaal answer.

But I think it's important to mention this official nginx article, posted in 2016, it clearly explains nginx behaviour on this matter and the possible solutions:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/

We indeed have to "Set the Domain Name in a Variable" and use the [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?&_ga=2.57162154.1878583232.1498096440-1109583619.1496884239#resolver) directive.

however, using a variable changes the rewrite behaviour. You may have to use the rewrite directive, it depends on your location and proxy_pass setup.

*PS: would have post a comment but not enough points yet...*

Answer (score 12):

ohaal's answer takes most of us there, but there is a case where the DNS resolver does not live at 127.0.0.1 (eg when you're in a special containerized environment)

In that case, you may want to change the nginx conf to `resolver ${DNS_SERVER};`. Then, before you start nginx, run

```
export DNS_SERVER=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf |grep -i '^nameserver'|head -n1|cut -d ' ' -f2)
envsubst '${DNS_SERVER}' < your_nginx.conf.template > your_nginx.conf
```

Note, that you need the `gettext` package installed, as that provides the `envsubst` command.

Comment: awk '/nameserver/{a=(a?a" "$2:$2)} END{print a}' /etc/resolv.conf 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 2):

I've hacked together a script to watch a conf.d folder upstreams for dns changes and reload nginx upon detection.  It's a first pass, and surely can be improved (next pass, I'll use nginx -T to parse upstreams specifically. Same idea could be used for proxy_pass directives):

```
#!/bin/bash

get_upstreams() {
  local files=$@
  grep -hEo '(server\s+)[^:;]+' $files | cut -d' ' -f 2
}

resolve_hosts() {
  local hosts=$@
  for h in $hosts; do dig +short $h; done | sort -u
}

watch_dir=$1

[ -d $watch_dir ] || exit 2

upstreams=$(get_upstreams $watch_dir/*)
ips=$(resolve_hosts $upstreams)
if [ ! "$ips" ]; then
  echo "Found no resolvable hosts in $watch_dir files."
fi

host_hash=$(echo $ips | /usr/bin/sha512sum)

echo $host_hash
echo $ips

while [ -d $watch_dir ]; do
  sleep 30
  upstreams=$(get_upstreams $watch_dir/*)
  ips=$(resolve_hosts $upstreams)
  new_hash=$(echo $ips | /usr/bin/sha512sum)
  if [ "$host_hash" != "$new_hash" ]; then
    echo Detected an upstream address change.  $ips
    echo Reloading nginx
    echo $new_hash
    echo $ips
    /sbin/service nginx reload
    host_hash=$new_hash
  fi
done
```

Comment: do you have a solution which works with `nginx -T` and `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 1):

The most voted answer from @ohaal didn't work for me. I had to use a variant of the proposed solution:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=10s;

location ~ ^/SomePath/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://dynamic.example.com:80/SomePath/$1$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/Other/Path/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://dynamic.example.com:80/Other/Path/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Unlike the other solution, this works also of for urls like:

```
http://proxied:80/SomePath/bla
http://proxied:80/SomePath/bla/bla?whatever=123
http://proxied:80/Other/Path/bla
http://proxied:80/Other/Path/bla/bla
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8130872/948938