# when doing request through nginx with domain as server_name, whenever i change the ip of the domain, it still redirects to previous ip

Tags: nginx

I have a basic nginx as a reverse proxy which all it does is adding header to requests and proxy pass. I have there my `domain as the server_block`.

If lets say the environement fall, i want to change the ip of my domain, so everything will still work and i only have to change the ip of my domain and nothing more.

Now, whenever i change the ip of my domain, nginx still proxy to the old ip (which is down) and not the current ip. but whenever i redeploy the nginx, the problem is solved and it proxy to the current ip.

Now maybe it's some kind of cache or something like that, is there a way to cancel it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force nginx to resolve DNS (of a dynamic hostname) everytime when doing proxy\_pass?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p)

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks, I'll try this, btw do you know what does this line means: resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353 valid=30s; . I tried  to look for it but didn't understand. and do i also put localhost and port 5353, even if the nginx runs on another port?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver It’s address of DNS

Comment: @AlexeyTen so If my address is lets say 200.83.1.57 and im running on port 8080 I put 200.83.1.57 [::1]:8080; ? also if i have to do it, and lets say i then change the ip of the site, i have to update it right? - and it's not dynamic to ip change, and I do need it to be dynamic becuase i don't want to redeploy it when ip changes. or maybe setting a varaible for the proxy pass is good enough? what do you thing?