# nginx force nginx to resolve dns - error 9#9 recv() (failed connection refused)

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I have a hostname like this: https://abc.xyz.com

I want to force resolve the dns everytime a request arrives, because if the dns of abc.xyz.com changes i want nginx to still be able to proxy to the site, therefore need to resolve the dns again.

Now i followed this post [How to force nginx to resolve DNS (of a dynamic hostname) everytime when doing proxy_pass?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p) and my configuration looks like this

```
server {
    ...
    resolver abc.xyz.com;
    set $backend "http://abc.xyz.com";
    proxy_pass $backend;
    ...
}
```

And i get this error `[error] 9#9 recv() failed (111: connection refused) while resolving, resolver: <some-dns>:53`

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here, i guess it has something to do with the resolver. The only difference is that the guy in the post put dns there `127.0.0.1`. I don't think i want to do that since dns/ip can change when i redploy my app and i saw you can give resolver a hostname but it doesn't work and i get this error.

Any help would be appreatiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resolver` tells which DNS recursive server is used to resolve the domain name. You need to point it to your DNS server's IP address.

Comment: so if im understanding correcty, my application is not the dns server?
 and i need to figure out my dns-server's hostname (like dns-server.dns.com) or their dns( im assuming their dns doesnt change)?

Comment: You need to add your DNS resolver's IP address to the directive.

Comment: do you know where/how do I find that? sorry if its obvious and im stupid

Comment: You need to ask your hosting provider what are their DNS addresses.