# Nginx proxy_pass doesn't always work when using a variable for the host

Tags: nginx

I have 2 location blocks with proxy_pass configs, they look in a simplified form like this:

```
location ^~ /location1/ {
  set $backend1 https://service1.example.com;
  proxy_pass $backend1;
}

location ^~ /location2/ {
  rewrite /location2/(.*) /new/base/path/$1 break;
  set $backend2 https://service2.example.com;
  proxy_pass $backend2;
}
```

Now the problem is `location1` works fine, but `location2` doesn't, it returns 500, and I get this error in the logs

```
2022/09/26 18:07:42 [error] 25952#25952: *263 invalid URL prefix in "", client: 123.123.123.123, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /location2/my/url HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/referrer/page"
```

If I set the value with a variable, like this:

```
location ^~ /location2/ {
  rewrite /location2/(.*) /new/base/path/$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://service2.example.com;
}
```

then it works. I need to use a variable though, because it helps forcing nginx re-resolve the DNS ([as mentioned in this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/593003/321062))

What I noticed from the error log line is that the variable `$backend2` is empty, which gets clearer if I define it like this

```
set $backend2 service2.example.com;
proxy_pass https://$backend2;
```

which will out put an error like this instead:

```
2022/09/26 18:07:42 [error] 25952#25952: *263 invalid URL prefix in "https://", client: 123.123.123.123, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /location2/my/url HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/referrer/page"
```

So what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem, that I only realised after posting it.

The problem for me was defining the variable in the location block. Defining it outside the location block was sufficient to resolve the issue.

```
set $backend2 https://service2.example.com;
location ^~ /location2/ {
  rewrite /location2/(.*) /new/base/path/$1 break;
  proxy_pass $backend2;
}
```

No clue how did it work in other location blocks though.